# How to get daily, weekly and monthly report in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
public function index(){
    $this->load->model(array('msellproduct','minvoice'));
    $invoice=$this->minvoice->get_many_by(array('vendor_id'=>$this->cuseridentity->get_data( 'id' ),'create_time'=>date("Y-m-d")));
    $week=$this->minvoice->get_many_by(array('vendor_id'=>$this->cuseridentity->get_data( 'id' ),'create_time' =>" DATE_SUB(".date('Y-m-d').",INTERVAL 1 WEEK)"));
    $month=$this->minvoice->get_many_by(array('vendor_id'=>$this->cuseridentity->get_data( 'id' ),'create_time'=>"DATE_SUB(".date("Y-m-d").",INTERVAL 1 Month"));
    $product=$this->msellproduct->get_many_by(array('vendor_id'=>$this->cuseridentity->get_data( 'id' )));
    var_dump($week);
    $this->_render( 'index', array(
        'model' => null,
        'product'=>$product,
        'invoice'=>$invoice,
        'week'=>$week,
        'month'=>$month,
    ) );
}
```

In the above function I am getting the daily report. That is correct, but I don't get the weekly and monthly report.

Comment: Improved spelling and removed footer.

Answer (score 0):

Get and convert date using PHP and put (Pass) just date not SQL date functions.
For example:

```
public function index(){
    $this->load->model(array('msellproduct','minvoice'));
    $invoice=$this->minvoice->get_many_by(array('vendor_id'=>$this->cuseridentity->get_data( 'id' ),'create_time'=>date("Y-m-d")));
    //Calculate date here if your SQL is taking just date
    $week_date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d"))-(7*24*60*60);
    $month_date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d"))-(30*24*60*60); //you can get days in the current month too
    $week=$this->minvoice->get_many_by(array('vendor_id'=>$this->cuseridentity->get_data( 'id' ),'create_time' =>date("Y-m-d",$week_date)));
    $month=$this->minvoice->get_many_by(array('vendor_id'=>$this->cuseridentity->get_data( 'id' ),'create_time'=>date("Y-m-d",$month_date)));
    $product=$this->msellproduct->get_many_by(array('vendor_id'=>$this->cuseridentity->get_data( 'id' )));
    var_dump($week);
    $this->_render( 'index', array(
        'model' => null,
        'product'=>$product,
        'invoice'=>$invoice,
        'week'=>$week,
        'month'=>$month,
    ) );
}
```

Most probably your Query takes dates so make it simple just calculate date using PHP and pass that date to your SQL if your SQL just take date parameter same as daily. According to the daily report what i got is your SQL is taking simply a date. In your way that can be done too but for now without your SQL code its easy to do in this way.